# Docker - Choosing project structure - Image as sub directories

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose

I have following components of a system:

```
master.py
pendant.py
common_code/
```

And I can organise my docker project with two different ways:

1. Store all code in one folder, then build an image which contains all code and use two dockerfiles with different `CMD` commands (`CMD [ "python", "master.py" ]`  and `CMD [ "python", "pendant.py" ]` in my case).
2. Use folder structure like this:

   ```
   master/
       Dockerfile
       master.py
   pendant/
       Dockerfile
       pendant.py
   common_code/
   docker-compose.yml
   ```

Which of them is preferable?

Comment: Depends on what you want, I guess. One way would be to define a common image that has all of the code, and then build two images based on the common image that override the `CMD` of the common image.

Comment: You can also just build one image with everything and then let the user specify the file to run as a parameter when starting the container.

Comment: Docker doesn't allow to copy common_code like `COPY ../common_code /` causing error: `Forbidden path outside the build context: ../common_code`